# Como somar tudo no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como faço para somar tudo de uma tabela no *MySQL* por exemplo..

Tenho a tabela `tb_comment`, ai quero somar em cada `post(id_mark)` a quantidade de rate que vai ter ao total.

Por exemplo o `id_user 20` tem o rate de 4 na `id_mark 10` e o `id_user 21` tem o rate de 5 na `id_mark 10` e vai dar 9 ao total como faço pra selecionar isso em PDO ?

[image: Tabela:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O MySQL tem a função `SUM( )`, adequada para sua necessidade.

Aqui estou agrupando pelo id_user, mas pode ser por outro campo, depende do objetivo:

```
SELECT SUM(rate) AS total GROUP BY id_user
```

Se quiser somar tudo, independente do id_user basta isso:

```
SELECT SUM(rate) AS total
```

Nos dois casos, o `AS total` é o que dá o nome do campo que você vai usar para recuperar o resultado. Note que você deve por um nome que não conflite com alguma coluna já existente na tabela.

Update: de acordo com seu comment, se quiser de um usuário só basta isso:

```
SELECT SUM(rate) AS total WHERE id_user = (id do usuario desejado)
```

não precisa nem do GROUP BY nesse caso.

Comment: Isso está correto?: SELECT id_mark, SUM(rate) as rate FROM tb_comment GROUP BY id_mark WHERE id_mark=:post_id

Comment: ou seria isso??:: SELECT SUM(rate) AS total GROUP BY id_user WHERE id_mark=:post_id

Comment: e para mim selecionar por exemplo todos os valores da id_mark só que contando como '1' cada valor?? e não 7 como está na imagem

Comment: @WilliamAlvares não entendi direito. Se quer saber só a quantidade de linhas, pode usar COUNT()

Comment: Sim só a quantidade de linhas.. Pode me dar um exemplo ?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS linhas, SUM(rate) AS total FROM tb_comment WHERE id_user = .....

Answer (score 2):

Talvez esse link ajude: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/037f4439-9ea3-4db7-be84-61616ddf64d9/somar-valores-da-coluna-do-banco-de-dados-mysql-e-c?forum=vscsharppt.

Soma o valor de uma coluna

```
SELECT SUM(COLUNA) FROM TABELA
```